# How to handle Paste(Ctrl+v or with mouse) event in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to call a function when something is pasted on to a text area in my vue.js application. In this case in which event should I call my function?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can simply use the `paste` event:

```
<textarea @paste="onPaste"></textarea>

...
  methods: {
    onPaste (evt) {
      console.log('on paste', evt)
    }
  }
...
```

It's not a vue-specific event. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/paste

Comment: Thanks for this answer. In Vue 2.5.x, I had to wrap the logic inside `onPaste` in `this.$nextTick`. Without that, `evt.target.value` was not updated properly. I.e., on first paste, it was `undefined`. On second paste, it was equal to the value I pasted the first time.

Comment: To get the value being pasted, use `evt.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')`

Answer (score 21):

Using the `onPaste` method in Vue 2.6, the `evt.target.value` is empty. To get the text value, use:

```js
  methods: {
    onPaste (evt) {
      console.log('on paste', evt.clipboardData.getData('text'))
    }
  }
```

Comment: In the latest browsers, you must use `evt.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')`

Answer (score 18):

Additionally you can disable Past event (CTRL+V) for an input, with the **.prevent** function.

```
<input v-model="input" @paste.prevent class="input" type="text">
```

Past action will be automatically disabled for this input

Comment: This works perfectly! Not sure if this is better than the accepted answer but definitely easy to implement. Works with keyboard paste and mouse paste.

Answer (score 1):

The onPaste method needs to return true for text to be actually pasted.

Using the example above from @CodinCat, and updating it.

```
<textarea @paste="onPaste"></textarea>

...
  methods: {
    onPaste (evt) {
      console.log('on paste', evt)
      return true;
    }
  }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It is already done and wrapped into `watch` functionality, and it also handles "cut" event (with mouse) and keyboard keys too.

All you need is to set watcher to your property like so

```
data: {
    coupon_code: '',        
},
watch: {
    coupon_code: function(){
        console.log('watch-'+this.coupon_code);
    },
},
```

and HTML

```
<input type="text" autocomplete='off' v-model="coupon_code" >
```

[documenation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a lot of varied answers on here, many of which I would flag during a peer code review.

The shortest amount of code to compensate for pasting **(including keyboard shortcuts)** would be:

```
<textarea **@input**="doSomething" />.
```

You shouldn't be using `@keyup`, `keydown`, etc. for handling text input.

See - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Note: KeyboardEvent events just indicate what interaction the user had with a key on the keyboard at a low level, providing no contextual meaning to that interaction. **When you need to handle text input, use the input event instead.** Keyboard events may not be fired if the user is using an alternate means of entering text, such as a handwriting system on a tablet or graphics tablet.